# How to determine why this executable crashes on start? (C on *nix)

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

So I've got an application that builds and runs fine.   I started playing with some compiler settings on a bunch of the 20+ static and dynamic libraries it links to, and the app consistently crashes on start at a particular point.

I reverted my build system mods, and and the app is fine again.  (However, I forgot to make note of the changes I actually made...)

Purely as a matter interest, since I still have a copy of the bad binary (built in debug mode), I'd like to try and reverse engineer what I did exactly to screw things up.  :-)

Attaching a debugger, I can see that a function in a `.so` is passing to the main app, via a function call, a function pointer for the main app to use as a callback.

In the frame of the caller (in the `.so`) the function pointer has one value.  In the frame of the callee (in the main app), the function pointer magically has a different value.

When the main app attempts to call the stored function pointer, the program crashes with a segfault (mapper error).  The function pointer seems to still have the 2nd value which is presumably wrong.

Any suggestions on how to pick this apart?

---

**Update:** More details as requested.

Crash is at:

```
 0xfffffffffffeac58 ???????? ()
 0x000000000063a040 app_exec_callbacks()
 0xfffffd7ffea14514 dynlib_stuff ()
 0x000000000063a15e other_app_stuff () 
 0x00000000004d10a3 app_stuff ()
 0x0000000000499f20 main ()
```

Prior to this, the function `dynlib_do_setup()` passes a function pointer ( of `dynlib_callback_handler()`) to the app via a call to `app_register_callback()`.

Using a debugger, I can see that within `dynlib_do_setup()` the function pointer has a value of `0xfffffd7ffea13fa0`. Inside the function body of `app_register_callback()` the parameter suddenly has a value of `0xfffffffffffeac58`

Thus, the garbage value of `0xfffffffffffeac58` is stored in the app's callback table, and not surprisingly, the app crashes when that callback address is called as you can see in the stack trace above.

Again, purely as a matter of educational interest, how/why can this magical corruption happen?  How/why did reverting my build system changes suddenly fix this?

Thank you

Comment: post your `bt`. It will save you a lot of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

**Compiler bug** as the result a certain optimization flag combo.  Known but not fixed for the past 3 years.  :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already figured out what was going on. Perhaps there was something strange that happened while linking (maybe relating to [relocations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29)?) that caused main() to not have the correct address for the function pointer.